# Removing parts of the path from string

Tags: c#, regex

Consider the following string

```
string path = @"\\ParentDirectory\All_Attachments$\BATCH_NUMBERS\TS0001\SubDirectory\FileName.txt";
```

I am trying to modify the path by removing the `\\ParentDirectory\All_Attachments$\`. So I want my final string to look like:

```
BATCH_NUMBERS\TS0001\SubDirectory\FileName.txt
```

I have come up with the following `regex`

```
string pattern = @"(?<=\$)(\\)";

string returnValue = Regex.Replace(path, pattern, "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

With the above if I do `Console.WriteLine(returnValue)` I get

```
\\ParentDirectory\All_Attachments$BATCH_NUMBERS\TS0001\SubDirectory\FileName.txt
```

So it only removes `\` can someone tell me how to achieve this please.

Comment: What is the general rule?  Do you want to remove the first 2 variably named  directories?

Comment: @AlexK. Yes I want to remove the first two named directories

Comment: Does the first directory always start with \\ or could a valid path be C:\Foo\Bar ?

Comment: @Stuart It will always start with \\

Comment: Do not need regex.  Can use string method : string result = string.Join("\\",path.Split(new char[] {'\\'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Skip(2));

Comment: @jdweng can you make your comment into an answer and i'll accept it

Comment: @Downvoter can you please explain why?

Comment: You've got some working answers, and I don't know if you're interested, but no one explained why your pattern didn't work, so: You're using a positive look-behind - `(?<=\$)`. This will only match the **position** before a dollar sign and no characters. It won't match everything up to it, as I think you assume. So the only character matched, and replaced, is the backslash.

Comment: @ClasG Thanks for the explaination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below should do the trick.

```
string path = @"\\ParentDirectory\All_Attachments$\BATCH_NUMBERS\TS0001\SubDirectory\FileName.txt";
var result = Regex.Replace(path, 
@"^      # Start of string
[^$]+    # Anything that is not '$' at least one time
\$       # The '$ sign
\\       # The \ after the '$'
", String.Empty, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

When executed in [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) it gives the following result:

> BATCH_NUMBERS\TS0001\SubDirectory\FileName.txt

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `Substring()` and `IndexOf()` to accomplish your goal:

```
string result = path.Substring(path.IndexOf("$") + 1);
```

Comment: this results in `\BATCH_NUMBERS\TS0001\SubDirectory\FileName.txt` don't think the OP wants that first \, maybe path.indexof("$") + 2 ?

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Using a regex that takes the first 2 groups of (backslash(es) followed by 1 or more non-backslashes). And including the `$` and backslash after that.

```
string returnValue = Regex.Replace(path, @"^(?:\\+[^\\]+){2}\$\\", "");
```

Or by splitting on `$`, joining the string array without it's first element and then trim `\` from the start:

```
string returnValue = string.Join(null, path.Split('$').Skip(1)).TrimStart('\\');
```

But you'll be using System.Linq for that method to work.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative avoiding an RE or split/join you could just run along the string until you have seen 4 slashes:

```
string result = null;
for (int i = 0, m = 0; i < path.Length; i++)
    if (path[i] == '\\' && ++m == 4) {
        result = path.Substring(i + 1);
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help